# How to bypass/disable Foreign Key Constraints on Laravel Queries

Tags: php, laravel, laminas

> Laminas\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException
> Statement could not be executed (23000 - 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lms`.`student_course_logs`, CONSTRAINT `student_course_logs_lecture_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`lecture_id`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE))
> http://localhost/public/student/course/loglecture

I'm having this foreign key constraints in my query. How do I solve this one? Would it be possible to bypass foreign key contraints?

Here's my error log: https://flareapp.io/share/omwaaZR7#F51

Thank you.

Comment: You could remove the constraint, but why? It has a good purpose. It's telling you you're trying to add a value as a foreign key which does not exist in the primary table. Normally this would cause an inconsistency and likely lead to other problems later down the line. The database is, correctly, preventing you from making a mistake. You need to correct the data problem, instead of looking for workarounds. If you've studied relational database design hopefully you understand the concepts involved here. If you haven't studied it, now would be a good time.

Comment: P.S. The only reason why you'd remove a foreign key is if the key itself is actually a design mistake. You  haven't shown your schema but it looks like you have a key between two fields called `lecture_id` and `courses.id`. To me, a lecture and a course are not the same kind of entity - I'd guess a course can contain many lectures. So _maybe_ the key is specified incorrectly...but we'd need to see your schema and some sample data, and for you to explain the real-world structure you're trying to represent, in order to know if that's true or not.